# Knockout with table and array not working

Tags: json, knockout.js

This employee variable I am getting it from local storage.

My HTML

```html
<table id='exampletable' align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>TicketNumber</th>
            <th>TargetDate</th>
            <th>SiteID</th>
            <th>ServiceType</th>
            <th>AssignedTOEmpName</th>
            <th>TicketStatus</th>
            <th>complaintDescription</th>
            <th>ReportingPersonPhoneNumber</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: addresses">
        <tr >
            <td><a href='newticket.html'><img data-bind="click: $parent.SelectTicket" src='./images/edit.png' border='0'/></a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: TicketNumber"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: TargetDate"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: SiteID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ServiceType"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: AssignedTOEmpName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: TicketStatus"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: complaintDescription"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ReportingPersonPhoneNumber"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
var employee = getjson("emp");

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]); 
    ko.mapping.fromJS(employee.tasks, {}, self.addresses);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

//function binding work order details to view
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

data

```
employee = {
    "querySucess": true,
    "SelfEmployeeView": {
        "FirstName": "Binesh ",
        "LastName": "Dadiya",
        "CompanyID": "xyz",
        "ReportingManager": {
            "FirstName": "Mohammad",
            "LastName": "Saeef"
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "fetchedDateandtime": "Apr 22, 2015 2:16:48 PM",
            "isSupervisor": false,
            "TicketNumber": "MyTT876",
            "TargetDate": "Aug 29, 2014",
            "CustomerName": "PQR",
            "SiteID": "STID",
            "ServiceType": "PM",
            "GeneralIssuesList": "EBCNC",
            "TicketStatus": "CU",
            "ReportingPersonName": "Kashim Khan",
            "ReportingPersonPhoneNumber": "790"
        },
        {
            "fetchedDateandtime": "Apr 22, 2015 2:16:48 PM",
            "isSupervisor": false,
            "TicketNumber": "MyTT876",
            "TargetDate": "Aug 29, 2014",
            "CustomerName": "PQR",
            "SiteID": "STID",
            "ServiceType": "PM",
            "GeneralIssuesList": "EBCNC",
            "TicketStatus": "CU",
            "ReportingPersonName": "Kashim Khan",
            "ReportingPersonPhoneNumber": "790"
        },
        {
            "fetchedDateandtime": "Apr 22, 2015 2:16:48 PM",
            "isSupervisor": false,
            "TicketNumber": "MyTT876",
            "TargetDate": "Aug 29, 2014",
            "CustomerName": "PQR",
            "SiteID": "STID",
            "ServiceType": "PM",
            "GeneralIssuesList": "EBCNC",
            "TicketStatus": "CU",
            "ReportingPersonName": "Kashim Khan",
            "ReportingPersonPhoneNumber": "790"
        },
        {
            "fetchedDateandtime": "Apr 22, 2015 2:16:48 PM",
            "isSupervisor": false,
            "TicketNumber": "MyTT876",
            "TargetDate": "Aug 29, 2014",
            "CustomerName": "PQR",
            "SiteID": "STID",
            "ServiceType": "PM",
            "GeneralIssuesList": "EBCNC",
            "TicketStatus": "CU",
            "ReportingPersonName": "Kashim Khan",
            "ReportingPersonPhoneNumber": "790"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have neither described your problem nor asked a question. That's kind of useless, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, data is missing properties:

AssignedTOEmpName

complaintDescription

When you add even empty values you will get it working.

```
{
  "fetchedDateandtime": "Apr 22, 2015 2:16:48 PM",
  "isSupervisor": false,      
  "TicketNumber": "MyTT876",
  "TargetDate": "Aug 29, 2014",
  "CustomerName": "PQR",
  "SiteID": "STID",
  "ServiceType": "PM",
  "GeneralIssuesList": "EBCNC",
  "TicketStatus": "CU",
  "AssignedTOEmpName": '',
  "complaintDescription" :'',
  "ReportingPersonName": "Kashim Khan",
  "ReportingPersonPhoneNumber": "790"
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7rwnj1td/1/

Comment: Sorry folks, code worked perfectly fine, only issue was property names started with lower case.

Comment: This may help others, when you store data using localStorage.setItem, the json properties first letter will be changed to smll instead of capital e.g. TicketNumber will become ticketNumber!! Thank you all for help. I apologies for wasting your precious time.

Comment: One more thing, I would like to add here, when you fetch json from server and store it in localstorage and read again, you need to stringify it before use, and again json.parse the stringify data to use it as array!!